# Python - Pandas - Filter out columns based on row average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with several columns and a date index:

```
TIME           A         B          C              D              E 
---------------------------------------------------------------------    
2015-03-01   0.74      -0.70       2.62           2.64           3.43   
2015-03-02   0.15      -1.28       0.56           400.58         0.08   
2015-03-03  -0.18      -3.82       0.21           0.22          -0.32   
2015-03-04  -1.45      -1.26       0.74           0.76          -0.09   
2015-03-05 -13.01     -12.88     -16.46         -16.45         -11.67   
2015-03-06 -47.73     -57.09     -55.45         -55.51         -55.15   
2015-03-07  -2.31      -3.57     -36.24         -39.50           2.87   
2015-03-08   0.64       0.34       1.76           1.75           1.51
```

And I want to remove any column that has at least one entry where the value is not within 100 of the row average.

In other words, if the average of all the columns for date 2015-03-02 is 80.018, I only want to keep the columns that have a value between -19.982 and 180.018 for this specific date. So in this example, I would exclude column D because it has a value outside that range.

I don't want to have to loop through the dataframe's rows either, so I'm looking for a very pythonic solution.

Comment: I think you misread my question. My example is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
#if necessary create DatetimeIndex
df = df.set_index('TIME')

#get mean per rows
s = df.mean(axis=1)
#create boolean mask by +/- 100 chained by OR (|)
m = (df.gt(s + 100, axis=0) ) | (df.lt(s - 100, axis=0))

#remove column by condition - inverted mask with any for check at least one True
df = df.loc[:, ~m.any()]
print (df)
                A      B      C      E
TIME                                  
2015-03-01   0.74  -0.70   2.62   3.43
2015-03-02   0.15  -1.28   0.56   0.08
2015-03-03  -0.18  -3.82   0.21  -0.32
2015-03-04  -1.45  -1.26   0.74  -0.09
2015-03-05 -13.01 -12.88 -16.46 -11.67
2015-03-06 -47.73 -57.09 -55.45 -55.15
2015-03-07  -2.31  -3.57 -36.24   2.87
2015-03-08   0.64   0.34   1.76   1.51
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m)
                A      B      C      D      E
TIME                                         
2015-03-01  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-02  False  False  False   True  False
2015-03-03  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-04  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-05  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-06  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-07  False  False  False  False  False
2015-03-08  False  False  False  False  False
```

Another solution:

```
m = (df.lt(s + 100, axis=0) ) & (df.gt(s - 100, axis=0))

#check all Trues per columns
df = df.loc[:, m.all()]
```

---

```
print (m)
               A     B     C      D     E
TIME                                     
2015-03-01  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-02  True  True  True  False  True
2015-03-03  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-04  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-05  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-06  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-07  True  True  True   True  True
2015-03-08  True  True  True   True  True
```